# Streaming on windows store applications

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-store

I'm curently creating a live streaming application and i am stuck with playing a stream in windows store applications is there a way to play a rstp stream link or m3u8 stream link on windows store application if it is possible can someone tell me a way to do it!! And is it possible to embed a vlc player to a windows store app to play above mentioned steam types!!

Comment: I think you can download and compile the WinRT-compatible source of libvlc, but it likely won't be a simple or streamlined process. For RSTP I would check out [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp), though it's not guaranteed that it will build for WinRT out of the box. For m3u8 check out [this](http://www.3ivx.com/technology/windows/metro/http_live_streaming.html), or parse the playlist manually. I believe `MediaElement` supports HLS out of the box.

Comment: parse the playlist manually how can i do that is there a sample or something if it is possible could you please guide me with the following steps thank you!!

Comment: Well, m3u8 is basically a text file with a specific structure. It has a bunch of different lines and each line tells you something. Some of them are metadata about a given value, some are the url of the value. Open up the m3u8 file like you would a text document, then read it in one line at a time and read what is in the line. If it's a URL, then you can try setting up a stream to that url. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) for the file's schema.